# The right way to do preg_match and preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

So I have been trying to bring back to life my very old website.

I started with replacing ereg with preg, but it's been a very long time since I have written any PHP.

At the moment I am stuck on this:

```
$_POST['amount'] = preg_replace("/[^0-9/]",'',$_POST['amount']);
$_POST['amount'] = round($_POST['amount']);

if (!preg_match('/[^0-9]/', $_POST['amount'])) {
    echo "Invalid amount.";
}else {
     echo "Passed";
}
```

I'm not entirely sure where I am going wrong. Should it be `!preg_match` or `preg_match` for example?

Edit:
`$_POST['amount']` allows a user to enter a number and needs to replace anything else other than a number if attempted.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I saw the post you said is the same as mine but it didn't seem to make sense to me, it seems different to what I am trying to achieve...?

Comment: [`is_numeric()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) seems like the simplest. Or maybe [`filter_var()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

Comment: I'm not sure what Floating point numbers are but users will be required to enter a number like 1234. What I am trying to use preg_replace and preg_match for is so the script stop/replaces entries like -1,2)3$4 to 1234. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: Always dangerous assuming you can second guess what the user ment to put in. Best to say, this aint right, have another try

Comment: Well I get what you mean but I have a JavaScript on the entry field which coverts the entry into currency. So if I enter 1234, it will make it £1,234 and this is really why I have this check on the PHP side.

Comment: That seems to be a longer way than just stripping down what they enter into just number...

Comment: Just numbers go into the DB, once this is fixed anyway...

Comment: In all this time you could have had a simple jiggle with that preg_replace and come up with `preg_replace("/[^0-9]/",'',$_POST['amount']);` Or looked at the answer below which I notice is basically saying the same thing

Comment: And if they are entering money with pence like `£999.00` ___Floating Point Basically___ then an addition of a dot would cope with that. `preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/",'', $_POST['amount']);`

Comment: That's what I have but it's not working. Can you see the error in my code?

Comment: You mean you changed your code to one I suggested above?

Comment: Or you think that your original code and my suggested or @jasonklai suggestions are the same?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the error is (i.e. what is the current output and what was expected). However, one mistake in the prompt is that the pattern for the first `preg_replace` appears to have a typo: `/[^0-9/]` should probably be `/[^0-9]/`

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/",'',$_POST['amount']);
```

The rest looks like correct syntax (i.e. `preg_match` returns `0` if there is no match).